# VBA to run only if filename = "xx"

Tags: vba

I would like the below to run only if a filename in the filepath location equals "xx". As it is currently it still opens files <> "xx". What am I missing here?

```
Sub UpdateMasterLog()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim erow1
Dim Filepath1

If FileName = "XX" Then

Filepath1 = "Z:\test folder"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath1)

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath1 & MyFile)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("A2:P" & LastRow).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2)

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: is this incomplete? I don't see where FileName comes from

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Filepath1 = "Z:\test folder"
Do While fileName <> ""

     If filename = "xx" then
           Workbooks.Open (Filepath1 & MyFile)
           ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
           LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,                
           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
           Range("A2:P" & LastRow).Copy
           ActiveWorkbook.Close
           ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2)
     End If

     Filepath1 = Dir()
Loop
```

Tell me what happens / use  this for now. Best!

Comment: I made the above adjustments and it does not open the file named "xx". Do I need to bring in filename and define it prior to the do while statement?

Comment: yea, filename is a variable that you defined. You need to define both the file name and path. After you have done that, open the proper file.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, @Kerry if it works, can you mark the question as correct so others with the same question can see the answer? Thanks!